# If you draw $4$ points for a uniform distribution $[0,1]$, what's the expected value of the smallest number?

Tags: probability, expected-value, order-statistics

Since this is a uniform distribution, can we just use symmetry for this, and say that our four numbers will be spaced apart, so they will be on the number line at the following locations:

$\frac{1}{5}$, $\frac{2}{5}$, $\frac{3}{5}$, $\frac{4}{5}$

Therefore, the smallest number is expected to be $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: "can we just use symmetry for this, and say that our four numbers will be spaced apart, so they will be on the number line at the following locations?" No, of course you can't. That's not "using symmetry", that makes no sense.

Comment: @leonbloy It gives the correct answer, so I think it makes sense. :)

Comment: @JamesFlanagin It happens to give the right answer because we are using the uniform distribution. Your argument would not work for any other distribution, and isn't mathematically sound.